# Java Main class cannot be found or loaded error

Tags: java, javafx, program-entry-point

I am new to JavaFX and currently I am trying to build a simple Stage with a few components inside. I have imported the **jfxrt.jar** file and I am able to use the libraries successfully in my class **App.java**. Howerver, when I run my code I get the following error message on the console:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class App
Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

This is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage firstStage) throws Exception {
       firstStage.setTitle("Image Processing App - Andromachi Rozaki");     
       Button button = new Button();
       button.setText("Open Image");

       StackPane layout = new StackPane();
       layout.getChildren().add(button);

       Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
       firstStage.setScene(scene);
       firstStage.show();
    }

}
```

Does anyone understand why this happens and how I could go about solving it? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I am running the `App.java` file in the link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHmTo.png)

Comment: are all necessary libraries provided sur the classpath?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to execute the right file? What's your setup?

Comment: @Nearoo I have updated my post

Comment: look for the path of jfxrt.jar and include it into the CLASSPATH of your computer. For example on Windows: CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;path_of_jfxrt.jar

Comment: Your JAR file doesn't mention `javafx.jar` or whatever it's called in its Class-path.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what IDE you are using but you may try to put this in your VM options

`--module-path PATH_TO_JAR --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Answer (score 0):

Thing is **JavaFX** is not bundled in current versions of **Oracle JDK**. 
I think you're using **Java 11**, and that means **JavaFX is not included**.

I understand you already downloaded JavaFX library, did you **included it as library** in your IDE?

From screenshot I don't understand which **IDE** you're using, but most times you can add the jar file into a folder of your project, right-click it and find an option like **add to project as library**. That might solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated the photo on my post. I have imported the library and I can see it under my referenced libraries... isnt the library imported now?

Comment: You still don't tell us which IDE you're using. Thing is: if you don't have errors at compile-time library should be correctly referenced.

Comment: oh sorry! I am using Eclipse

Comment: Eclipse IDE has plugins for JavaFX. Try looking for those on the Internet, otherwise you might try to install full **JavaFX SDK** from: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

Comment: @hispaniccoder One of the quirks of JavaFX is that if your main-class is a subclass of `Application` then the JavaFX modules **must** be on and used from the _modulepath_, not the _classpath_. This is true for at least JavaFX 11 through JavaFX 13. Check out [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) to see how to put the JavaFX libraries on the modulepath; it explains the procedure for the major Java IDEs and/or build tools.